# Assign alternative power button

Tags: linux, bios, firmware, button-remapping

I have an old laptop (C710) that has a broken power key and occasionally crashes or fails to boot.

How can I assign another key to be the power button such that I can use it to power off the computer when it is otherwise unresponsive?

Answer (score 1):

You are asking to

> power off the computer when it is otherwise unresponsive

When the computer is unresponsive, no (software) button assignments will work.

Some computers equipped with special docking station connector can have alternative power button on their docking station, but such a docking station support is not the case of C710.

So the only button alternative is on hardware level - fixing or replacing or creating parallel hardware button.

Answer (score 1):

Even the "Magic SysRq" key combinations don't work? I've unfortunately been using them a lot with recent Mint & Ubuntu versions (that are a lot less stable than the slightly older 14.04 - now Debian Stable - versions. I guess Debian really puts the "Stable" in Debian Stable)

Anyway, they're pressing combinations like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>SysRq</kbd>+ other keys, often R, E, I, S, U, B to "safely" sync, unmount & get a reboot, or O (instead of B) should shutdown.

Several are usually disabled in Debian & Ubuntu, but they can usually  be turned on & off with `/proc/sys/kernel/sysrq`

The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key) is surprisingly useful (with a picture & tables) or just search StackExchange or any web search